# MemoryError для fastText в бибилиотеке gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

Загружаю предобученный fasstext вот так:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText

model = FastText()
model.file_name = 'data/fasttext/cc.en.300.bin'
model.load()
```

Получаю `MemoryError`.  Как загрузить по-другому? Есть ли варианты хранить его где-нибудь в хранилище, без подгрузки? Или, быть может, использовать `annoy` как-то по-хитрому. Каждый раз загружать данны в память -- ресурсоёмкая операция и она нежелательна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти хорошего решения с использованием `gensim` не удалось. Данные взял с [офицального сайта](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html).

Были предложения использовать `mmap`. Но для загрузки `FastText`, использовать его также не получилось. Кроме того, без *ssd-диска* это вряд ли хорошо будет работать. Это загрузит в оперативную память только те страницы файла, к которым обратятся, может не помочь, если активный словарь будет достаточно велик.

Также была посоветована [ссылка](https://www.kaggle.com/thousandvoices/simple-lstm). Но, к сожалению, здесь приведено решение, которое использует `word2vec`, а значит, все преимущества `FastText` теряются. Детальнее. `FastText` здесь работать не будет в том смысле, что для слов не из словаря, будет получено исключение:

> `raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)`

Это произойдёт из-за того, что объект, который автор создаёт, является наследником `WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors`. И именно в этом базовом классе, определён метод, который, в конечном итоге, привёл меня к вышеуказанному исключению.

Но, разумеется, есть выход. В том же `package` есть

`from gensim.models import FastText`

Вот здесь всё по-другому. `__get_item__` здесь является устаревшим. И авторы предлагают обращаться напрямую к `wv`:

> `@deprecated("Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.__getitem__() instead")`

В `wv` при инициализации кладётся `FastTextKeyedVectors`. И здесь уже всё по-другому. Но память не вмещает весь корпус `FastText`

Решением оказалось, нативная загрузка данных и складирование их в [hnswIndex](https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib). *hnswIndex* хранит данные компактно и всё работает хорошо. Другим решением, будет использование [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy). *Annoy* умеет мапить данные на диск). Есть и [другие решения](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks). Пишем `FastTextReader`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm


class FastTextReader:
    def __init__(self, path, batch, use_tqdm=True):
        self.__fd = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='ignore')
        self.__vocab_size, self.__vec_dim = map(int, self.__fd.readline().split())
        self.batch = batch
        self.use_tqdm = use_tqdm

    @property
    def vocab_size(self):
        return self.__vocab_size

    @property
    def vec_dim(self):
        return self.__vec_dim

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.__fd.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        words = []
        vecs = []
        desc = 'FastText vectors\' reader progress bar'
        for i, line in tqdm(enumerate(self.__fd), disable=not self.use_tqdm, total=self.vocab_size, desc=desc):
            tokens = line.rstrip().split(' ')
            vecs.append(list(map(float, tokens[1:])))
            words.append(tokens[0])
            if i > 0 and i % self.batch == 0:
                yield words, vecs
                words = []
                vecs = []
        if len(words) != 0:
            yield words, vecs
        return
```

Пишем `wrapper` для индексера:

```
import json

import hnswlib
from sqlalchemy.testing.plugin.plugin_base import logging


class HNSWIndex:
    def __init__(self, folder, num_elements, dim, space='l2', M=16, ef_construction=200, ef=200):
        self.__prefix_logger = 'HNSF-Indexer'
        self.folder = folder
        self.__index = hnswlib.Index(space=space, dim=dim)
        self.__index.init_index(max_elements=num_elements, ef_construction=ef_construction, M=M)
        self.__mapping = dict()
        self.__max_id = None

    def save_index(self, mapping):
        logging.info('%s: dumping index' % self.__prefix_logger)
        self.folder.save_index(self.folder + 'index.bin')
        logging.info('%s: dumping keys' % self.__prefix_logger)
        with open(self.folder + 'keys.json', 'w') as fd:
            json.dump(mapping, fd)

    def add_items(self, vectors, labels):
        if self.__max_id is None:
            self.__max_id = 0
        keys = []
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            self.__mapping[i + self.__max_id] = label
            keys.append(i + self.__max_id)
            self.__max_id += 1

        self.__index.add_items(vectors, keys)
```

После этого можно производить `build_index` ([код](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) взять с офицального сайта) и модифицирован:

```
import readers
import indexers

data_path = 'data/'
fasttext_path = data_path+'fasttext/cc.ru.300.vec'
index_path = data_path+'fasttext_hnswlib_index'


def build_index(r, indexer):
    for words, vectors in r:
        indexer.add_items(vectors, words)
    return indexer


reader = readers.FastTextReader(path=fasttext_path, batch=50000)
indexer = indexers.HNSWIndex(folder=index_path, num_elements=reader.vocab_size, dim=reader.vec_dim)

build_index(reader, indexer)
```